# can you explain the logic of this query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this query that finds the name of the teacher with the 4-th highest salary. I don't understand this part

```
SELECT COUNT (DISTINCT T2.salary)
FROM teacher as T2
WHERE T2.salary > T1.salary
) = 3
```

from

```
SELECT name
FROM teacher as T1
WHERE (
SELECT COUNT (DISTINCT T2.salary)
FROM teacher as T2
WHERE T2.salary > T1.salary
) = 3;
```

The way I understand `count` is that it gives a final result, not that we can interrupt its work by specifying a number.

This is the `teacher` table: https://i.stack.imgur.com/arm8d.jpg
(I couldn't upload it here due to a server error)

Comment: Can you share what the teacher table looks like? Or if its a view/cte the definition

Answer (score 1):

Focusing on the subquery:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT T2.salary)
FROM teacher AS T2
WHERE T2.salary > T1.salary
```

This will return the count of distinct teachers having a salary *greater* than the teacher, in each row of the `teacher` table.  Asserting that this count be equal to 3 means that any matching teacher would have the 4th highest salary (since first 3 positions excluded).

Note that your logic should behave identically to `DENSE_RANK`.  You could also have used:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY salary DESC) rnk
    FROM teacher
)

SELECT name
FROM cte
WHERE rnk = 4;
```

Comment: You mean `in each row of the teacher table` ?

Comment: this subquery `SELECT COUNT (DISTINCT T2.salary) ...) = 3` isn't clear, because we usually should have done something `SELECT name FROM teacher as T1 WHERE`teacher_something = `(SELECT COUNT (DISTINCT T2.salary) FROM teacher as T2 WHERE T2.salary > T1.salary ) = 3;`

Comment: It is a correlated subquery and it seems clear to me.

Comment: You know, I solved very complex queries as a practice, but this one, I am sorry is so strange, and I can't get it, maybe I am dump, so be it. I don't get the link between the entries of T1 and the count that is returned. Absolutely a mystery tome

Comment: In plain English, your query is saying for each teacher, find the count of distinct other teachers having a higher salary.  When that count happens to be 3, then _keep_ that teacher as a match.  In the case of a match, that teacher must then have the 4th highest salary.

Comment: Yes, I understand this, but I don't know how the query syntax work

Comment: I mean, I did another query that is clearer: `SELECT T1.name, COUNT(DISTINCT T2.salary)
FROM teacher as T2, teacher as T1
WHERE T2.salary > T1.salary
group by T1.name
having COUNT(DISTINCT T2.salary) = 3;
`

Comment: But the logic for the other is so foreign to me, as I don't get what links the super query to the sub one

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't write it that way, but what it does is count, for each teacher, how many salaries are higher than his/her salary.

If 3 salaries are higher than a given teacher's salary then that teacher must be ranked 4th.

The performance of this query will be disastrous with large tables. You should use the `rank` window function instead.

Comment: There's no join in the subquery so it appears as though it counts all distinct salaries, not just a given teacher's

Comment: @Simeon so what if there's no join? there is a correlated sub query. It counts all distinct salaries higher than the main (T1) salary.

Comment: I see, sorry I misread your explanation

Comment: @JonathanJacobson you didn't explain what happens exactly, what do you mean by "If 3 salaries are higher than a given teacher's salary then that teacher must be ranked 4th."

Comment: @user20193231 the sub-query counts how many salaries are higher than the salary in T1. Is that clear?
Because of that, equating the sub query to 3 will give you teachers with 3 higher salaries.
Having 3 salaries higher than your own means you are number 4.

Comment: Yes, that s clear. But this subquery `SELECT COUNT (DISTINCT T2.salary) ...) = 3` isn't clear, because we usually should have done something `SELECT name FROM teacher as T1 WHERE` **teacher_something =** `(SELECT COUNT (DISTINCT T2.salary) FROM teacher as T2 WHERE T2.salary > T1.salary
) = 3;`