# strange WHERE clause in sql query ; WHERE (select ...) = 3

Tags: sql, postgresql

Usually with `WHERE` clause in SQL queries, in WHERE we check from the table if a condition is met, but with the following code:

```
SELECT name
FROM teacher as T1
WHERE (
SELECT COUNT (DISTINCT T2.salary)
FROM teacher as T2
WHERE T2.salary > T1.salary
) = 3;
```

This following sub-query `Sub` is returning a number.

```
(SELECT COUNT (DISTINCT T2.salary)
FROM teacher as T2
WHERE T2.salary > T1.salary)
```

but I don't understand how we check `WHERE Sub = 3`, it doesn't make sense to me. Can you explain?

The entire query finds the 4th highest salary of teacher.

Comment: The sub-query counts the number of salaries greater current teacher's one – and if there are three of current teacher is selected – so teachers with fourth highest salary (by value, not counting duplicates) are searched.

Comment: Thanks, but it's still not clear, in `where` clause we usually have this form `from table where condition` and the condition is related to the table;s row or something.

Comment: Your condition is of kind `x = y` where `y` is a fix value and `x` is the result of a sub-query returning exactly one value for each entry in the table to be tested.

Comment: Maybe a slightly less complex query of same pattern: `SELECT name FROM teacher WHERE salary > (SELECT AVG(salary) FROM teacher)` would select all teachers with a salary above the average – here in the sub-query there's no reference to current teacher, so the same value applies for all teachers...

Comment: @Aconcagua can you open a chat room to understand this query better?

Comment: @Aconcagua after some deep reading on sql, I see now what it means, but it was only due to your explanation. Thank you. If you can make your comment as an answer, I would mark it as an answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [can you explain the logic of this query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74053828/can-you-explain-the-logic-of-this-query)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a subquery anywhere where you can use an expression, so why not on the left side of the equality operator?

But this way to solve the problem is rather ugly. Why not

```
SELECT name
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT ON (salary)
             name, salary
      FROM teacher) AS t
ORDER BY salary DESC
OFFSET 3 FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY;
```

Comment: the question how the subquery returning 3 has anything to do with the where clause of the super query, the table T1 has no such number as 3, do you get me? If you can explain the step by step process what is being returned and how thing are computed

Comment: There is no requirement that a column is on either side of the `=`. 3 is just a number.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps more comprehensive with this query :

```
WITH T AS
(
SELECT name, COUNT(*) OVER(ORDER BY salary) AS N
FROM teacher as T1
)
SELECT name
FROM   T 
WHERE  N > 3
```